# Is it possible to assign a logon script to a user in a windows machine which is not a part of domain?

Tags: windows, windows-scripting

I have gone through the following link : 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918(v=ws.10).aspx.

It mentions that the  script should be saved in directory that corresponds to the domain controller's Netlogon shared folder.

So is it not possible assign a logon script to a local windows user account which doesnot belong to any domain.

Comment: Though this question is off-topic but that said, the answer is NO. You can't apply a GPO to a machine on a workgroup

Comment: But in the following link it says you can add logon scripts to a local user : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780963(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you meant when you mentioned Domain Controller netlogon share. Yes you can same way you apply script to domain accounts. You can add a script to the following locations **For Windows 7** C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup, that way anyone that logs onto the machine gets the script applied

Comment: I actually wanted to assign the logon script to a particular local user in a windows machine which is not a domain controller. I wanted to know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible. Put the script in a share on the local machine, edit the profile properties of the account and add the share location to the script under **logon script** But you also need to be sure what the script is meant to do.

Comment: 1 more doubt. Is that only possible through adding the logon script to a share?

Comment: Your best bet is to simply test and then you will know what's feasible and what's not or move your question to Super User where others running similar scenario would be able to help further. Is been a while I have done this